# the meaning of fish wife

Tags: meaning

the apparent image of a fishwife is one of a grouchy, rude, loud mouthed woman. 
So I thought about being this woman.  Smelling of fish 24 hours a day, every day of my life would make me grouchy.  Sleeping with a man who smelled like of fish 24/7 would make me even grouchier.  Watching people come to me to buy my fish, and then stick up their noses at the smell, would make me rude.  Because I am not the only fishwife selling my husband's catch, I know the one with the loudest voice will get the customers.  Perhaps this is how the image became set.

Comment: What’s you question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does "fishwife" mean "mean woman"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36076/why-does-fishwife-mean-mean-woman)

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. You need to be more specific on what you want to ask.

Comment: I voted it as a duplicate of Josh's question, but three users believed otherwise. The top answer on that question is virtually identical to deadrat's, but typically contains a bit more detail.

Answer (score 1):

A **fishwife** is a woman who sells fish.  She's not necessarily married to a fisherman.  *Wife* here is from the Old English *wif* meaning woman.  It's likely that fishwives got their reputation from having to cry their wares in the London fish market at Billingsgate, which itself has become a byword for profane verbal abuse.

Comment: @WS2 I wasn't aware that the old market was that Jewish in the first place.

Comment: Sorry - spellcheckers be cursed - the word was *genteel*! I will delete and repost. Having said that it probably was substantially Jewish - but I have no information on that.

Comment: As someone who visited the cramped old 16th century Billingsgate as a child in the 50s, before it moved out to a 13 acre site at Canary Wharf in 1982, let me confirm, as justified, its having been a byword for profane verbal abuse. My teenage vocabulary expanded in minutes. I have never been to the new market but doubt it is any more genteel than the old one, though rather less cramped